# Intel DX79SI won't work with RAID-1

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, raid

I built a brand new system, that has an Intel DX79SI mainboard, 16 GB DDR3 (four fours), nvidia geforce gtx 470 (from older system), coolermaster 700w psu from older system, intel core i7 3820, latest firmware on the mobo.  all the fans are working it seems,   the only alert i get is the SSD drive is over 100C.

When I first powered everything, the system routinely rebooted.  I let it sit for a day (because I had a business trip) and came back it booted fine.  I setup the SSD as a standalone to install a fresh copy of Windows 7 x64 on.  The RAID-1 was for data, a pair of 3 TB drives.  When I went into windows installer, it complained it was missing any device driver.  I got the "F6" drivers, but when I clicked browse, it found no drive (just the X drive where the installer copies it to ram).  The cdrom drivce wasnt even shown, no flash drive shown, so I just quit, changed bios from raid to ahci, it booted and installed fine.  Obviously, I rather have the data drives raided, and prefer the onboard raid since I don't want to spend even more money than i did on this since i went over budget to begin with.

Now every so often it still reboots while in Chrome, no bsod, just randomly reboots.  I am not sure if it is because the ssd is overheating.  I don't know if I screwed something up with the build.  I don't know if the two are related.  A colleague suggested it is the PSU.  It is about three years ago, 700w, the intel monitor states it is okay.

All the thermals are normal but ther ssd drive.  they are all stacked in the same spot, but the orhter drives arent even acxtive yet b/c of the raid not being on.

the ssd is on the 6 gb/s channel, the other two are on 3's i believe.

I really am out of ideas because if I can't access the RAID-1 on booting, its puzzling why all devices arent seen opn raid mode, because the ssd C drive isnt a raid member.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!